# Spotify audio feautures in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, spotify

I want to get the audio features of songs in spotify.

```
features = {}
all_track_ids = list(df['song_id'].unique())
start = 0
num_tracks = 100
while start < len(all_track_ids):
    tracks_batch = all_track_ids[start:start+num_tracks]
    features_batch = sp.audio_features(tracks_batch)
    features.update({ track_id : track_features 
                 for track_id, track_features in zip(tracks_batch, features_batch) })
    start += num_tracks

features['1mqlc0vEP9mU1kZgTi6LIQ']
```

The results(this is an example of a song):

```
{'danceability': 0.693,
'energy': 0.911,
'key': 9,
'mode': 1,
'speechiness': 0.0305,
'acousticness': 0.183,
'instrumentalness': 0.000107,
'liveness': 0.3,
'valence': 0.982,
'tempo': 125.895,
'type': 'audio_features',
'id': '1mqlc0vEP9mU1kZgTi6LIQ',
'uri': 'spotify:track:1mqlc0vEP9mU1kZgTi6LIQ',
'track_href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/1mqlc0vEP9mU1kZgTi6LIQ',
'analysis_url': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-analysis/1mqlc0vEP9mU1kZgTi6LIQ',
'duration_ms': 216520,
'time_signature': 4}
```

Now, I tried to create a dataframe with these songs and their features, this is a sample:

```
tracks = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(zip(tracks_batch, features_batch))
tracks


|song_id|features                                |
|:------|:--------------------------------------:|
|link   |{'valence:0.23', 'danceability:0.21',...|
```

How can I make this look like:

```
|song_id|valence|danceability|
|link   |0.23   |0.21        |
```

That is how to convert the dictionary into a Dataframe, whose column will be a feature of a song?
(I have a csv with a great deal of songs' ids.)

Comment: This might be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13575090/construct-pandas-dataframe-from-items-in-nested-dictionary

Comment: Googling "pandas dataframe from nested dictionary" finds lots of ideas

Comment: Is the first part of my code correct?

Comment: It seems so, as long as there aren't any duplicate track IDs in different batches.